# Writing a PDF outside ASP.NET MVC website folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, iis

I am trying to write a PDF file outside the ASP.NET MVC website folder and I get the following error:

*Cannot using a leading .. to exit above top directory*

We have another dataset static website that need not to be affected from website modifications and accidentally deleted. I suppose that the problem is the following line of code:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("../../Data/Invoices");
```

How can I workaround this limitation? I thought about disabling the Web Deploy option "Remove additional files a destination" but it's to risky, we need to maintain invoice copies for years. I'm scare from new DEV machine installations/new programmers, etc. We are working on Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.

Any other creative idea is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Server.MapPath("~") returns the physical path to the root of the application e.g. D:/WebSites/MyApp, but you cant go any higher

Comment: Do you think I am stepping back too much? I thought about a permission problem in writing inside a folder of a different website for IIS 7

Comment: If you wanted to write to say D:/WebSites/AnotherApp and both sites were running under same identity (say NetworkService) then I would think it's OK, but I don't know enough about security to be sure

Answer (score 0):

Even though the idea of keeping data on the application server makes me uncomfortable; you can use a virtual directory that points to a location like; `c:/Alberto/Data/Invoices` and map your virtual directory from your application to `http://{server}/albertos/invoices` (invoices would be your virtual directory and albertos would be the application name). Then I think you can call `Server.MapPath('~/invoices')` on it as you wish.